# onRotate getactivity is null

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, picasso

I'm using picasso to show bunch of images parsed from json in a gridview but on rotate app crashes and getActivity() in postexecute becomes null!

my Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_data, container, false);

        images_gv=(GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.images);
        new RetrieveItemData().execute();


        return v;
    }
```

Here is RetieveItemData class in my fragment:

```
 private class RetrieveItemData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ArrayList<String> imageList=new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(Constant.URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray images;
                    if(!jsonObj.isNull(TAG_IMAGES)) {
                      images=jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGES);
                        //looping through Features
                        for (int i = 0; i < images.length(); i++) {
                            imageList.add(images.getString(i));
                        }
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            imageAdapter=new GridViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), imageList);
            images_gv.setAdapter(imageAdapter);


        }

    }
```

And here is my adapter:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    final Context context;
    private List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> urls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.urls=urls;

    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_image_item, null);
        }


        ImageView  imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_item);

// Get the image URL for the current position.
        String url = getItem(position);

// Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
        Picasso.with(context) //
                .load(url) //
                .fit()
                .into(imageview);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override public int getCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override public String getItem(int position) {
        return urls.get(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    final class SquaredImageView extends ImageView {
        public SquaredImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public SquaredImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fragment that executed the task is no longer attached to an Activity. When the device's configuration changes (such as changing the device's orientation) the entire Activity is destroyed and recreated, so the system is creating an entirely new Activity (and attaching an entirely new Fragment).

The easiest solution is to cancel the task if the Fragment is destroyed. The newly created Fragment will initiate the task again. It means you might make the network connection twice so there is probably a more efficient solution for data usage, but it's not too bad since it's an unlikely occurrence to rotate while the data is loading.

You can achieve this by adapting your Fragment like so:

```
RetrieveItemData mRetrieveDataTask;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload_data, container, false);

    images_gv=(GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.images);

    mRetrieveDataTask = new RetrieveItemData();
    mRetrieveDataTask.execute();

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    mRetrieveDataTask.cancel(false);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it doesnt crash anymore but the progressdialog never gets closed!